# Question about limit of the summand

Tags: limits

I have the relation $z(t)=\underbrace{y(t)}_{\geq a>0,\forall t}+\underbrace{x(t)}_{\geq 0,\forall t}$. It is known that $\lim_{t\to 0}z(t)=a$.

My question is: can we conclude $\lim_{t\to 0}y(t)=a$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}x(t)=0$?

Comment: yes , just minorate $z(t)$ by$ a+x(t)$ then apply the limit

Comment: @mounirbensalem Thanks for your comment, but what's mean of minorate?

Comment: $z(t)=y(t)+x(t)\geq a+x(t)$
then apply the limit :$\lim_{t{\rightarrow 0}}z(t)=a\geq  a+\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} x(t)$
$\lim_{0}x(t)\leq 0 $, but $x(t)\geq 0$, for all t , so :$ \lim_{0}x(t)=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y(t) \geq a$ for all $t$, then $\lim_{t \to 0}y(t) \geq a$. If $x(t) \geq 0$ for all $t$, then $\lim_{t \to 0}x(t) \geq 0$. $$\lim_{t \to 0}z(t) =a= \lim_{t \to 0}y(t)+\lim_{t \to 0}x(t)$$gives $\lim_{t \to 0}y(t) = a$ and $\lim_{t \to 0}x(t) = 0$ by the initial remark.

Comment: How do you know the limits of $y(t)$ and $x(t)$ exist?

Comment: Oh, I thought that was part of the hypothesis. Let me think a bit

Comment: Yes, since both $y(t)$ and $x(t)$ are continuous, then their limits do exist.

Comment: All good then. I was trying to get a counter example using $\chi_{\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q}$ but it was being quite troublesome :P